# How to select only max pixel value to create new same size image from 2 images in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Assume I have 2 images with the same size, and these 2 images have similar pixel values, for example

```
img1 = [1 5 1 5,7 2 7 2, 3 9 3 9,8 4 8 4]; 
img2 = [5 1 5 1,2 7 2 7, 9 3 9 3,4 8 4 8];
```

I need to select only the max value from both of `img1` and `img2`. I want new image with

```
img3 = [5 5 5 5,7 7 7 7, 9 9 9 9,8 8 8 8];
```

In short, I want to compare all pixels in `img1` and `img2` and create new `img3` that contains max values from `img1` and `img2`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I must be missing something.  What is wrong with just:

```
  img3 = max(img1, img2);
```

Based on the documentation:

```
 MAX(X,Y) returns an array the same size as X and Y with the
    largest elements taken from X or Y. Either one can be a scalar.
```

So it should work as expected.

Well, I had to try to see for myself since everyone comes up with these sophisticated solutions.

```
    >> img1 = [1 5 1 5,7 2 7 2, 3 9 3 9,8 4 8 4];
    >> img2 = [5 1 5 1,2 7 2 7, 9 3 9 3,4 8 4 8];
    >> img3 = max(img1,img2);
    >> img3

    img3 =

 5     5     5     5     7     7     7     7     9     9     9     9     8     8     8     8
```

EDIT: had to check for myself with respect to the comment below (; in stead of ,):

```
    >> img1 = [1 5 1 5;7 2 7 2; 3 9 3 9;8 4 8 4];
    >> img2 = [5 1 5 1;2 7 2 7; 9 3 9 3;4 8 4 8];
    >> img3 = max(img1,img2);
    >> img3

    img3 =

         5     5     5     5
         7     7     7     7
         9     9     9     9
         8     8     8     8
```

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, extra step to do what?

Comment: @thang I just checked it as well, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @thang: Do you know any ways possible if we want to get the max from n martrix ? i.e max(img2, img2, img3, img4 ,.... imgn); it possible ? thank

Comment: @vhong, you can call max multiple times (*max(max(max(img1,img2),img3)...*), or use natan's solution. i.e.  create an MXMxn matrix then do max over the last dimension, but this costs more memory.

Answer (score 4):

img3 = img1 .* (img1 > img2) + img2 .* (img2 > img1);

Comment: no, not select only max value, I need the exactly the same size matrix as before. ANW thank

Comment: try the above code, img3 is the matrix with same size which has max of img1 and img2

Comment: img1 = [1 5 1 5; 7 2 7 2; 3 9 3 9; 8 4 8 4]; 
img2 = [5 1 5 1; 2 7 2 7; 9 3 9 3; 4 8 4 8];
img3 = img1 .* (img1 > img2) + img2 .* (img2 > img1);

Copy and paste exact same

Comment: oh yes it work :) thank. can I use this with grayscal image ?

Comment: is there a reason why you're going through all the trouble?  why not use max?  i don't get it....

Comment: @vhong :: actually u can just use what thang answered... u can use for gray/color anything...

Answer (score 1):

You can make a 3D matrix our of the two 2D arrays:

```
a(:,:,1)=img1;
a(:,:,2)=img2;
```

then

```
ans=max(a,[],3);
```

Comment: but if it is grayscal image. is it possible to use this code ?

Comment: and I want to create new image img3 with the same 3D matrix the sae like img1. not only it max value. thank again

Comment: @natan: for safety reasons, catenate along the n+1th dimension: `nd = ndims(img1);a = cat(nd+1,img1,img2); ans = max(a,[],nd+1);` (though thang's answer is still better)

Comment: thanks Jonas, I appreciate your feedback (and I agree regarding thang's answer)